# Hooking a Drupal Webform submission

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm developing a Drupal 7 website. The website has a couple of forms which take a users email address. As part of the process I need to be able to submit the email to a mailing list across an API.

I have all the calls written and tested for adding new users to mailing lists etc. What I'm not so sure of is how I get this code to run when the form is submitted on the Drupal site.

I assume there will be a hook function but I'm struggling to track it down. My forms are setup using Webforms module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hook_form_alter()` to hook in your webform instance & add an additional submit handler:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { 
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_{some id}')
    {
        array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'custom_webform_submit');
    }
}
```

Next in `custom_webform_submit()` execute your custom code:

```
function custom_webform_submit($form, $form_state) {
    // custom code here
}
```

Comment: I added the hook to my `theme.php` file but it doesn't seem to be hit. I added a `var_dump($form_id)` and `exit()` within the `hook_form_alter()` function to be sure. I also cleared the cache.